# How to get multiple values output from multiple fields with one _search request?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

On a performance testing project where ELK stack is used to collect and process API test data streams(samples/document go under one index) it would be good if we could get multiple aggregated results with only one _search request, like the count of successful requests AND average response time AND various percentiles, etc.
Is it possible to create such a DSL query or do we have to execute multiple searches like one to get the count of successful requests, another one for percentiles, etc?

Comment: it would be great if you can provide sample data and your current query and what is your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you sure can, [this page of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#run-multiple-aggs) gives an example, but here it is for reference;

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "aggs": {
    "my-first-agg-name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "my-field"
      }
    },
    "my-second-agg-name": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "my-other-field"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```